# Facing 401 error when exchanging Faceit OAuth authorization code for access token

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, oauth-2.0, oauth

I am stuck at the part of exchanging a code for a token on the Oauth with Faceit. Here is what is in the documentation:

```
Exchanging the Authorization Code for an Access Token
The 3rd party app makes a server to server call, posting the Authorization Code, Client
ID and Client Secret, the response will contain:
● an Access Token (used for calling FACEIT API on behalf of the User)
● an ID Token (a JWT that contains user information digitally signed by FACEIT)
● a Refresh Token (used for obtaining a new Access Token when the existing one
expires).
Your server makes the exchange by sending an HTTPS POST request. The POST
request is sent to the token endpoint, which you should retrieve from the OpenID
configuration endpoint using the key “token_endpoint”.
The request must use HTTP Basic Authentication "Authorization" header (using your
Client ID and Client Secret) and the application/x-www-form-urlencoded
“Content-type” header, including the following parameters in the POST body:
Field Description
code The one-time authorization code that is received on the
provided callback page
grant_type This field must contain the value "authorization_code", as
defined in the OAuth 2.0 specification
```

And my code looks like this

```
import axios from 'axios'
import qs from 'qs'

export async function authRoutes(app) {
  const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID
  const clientSecret = process.env.CLIENT_SECRET
  const credentials = `${clientId}:${clientSecret}`

  const base64Credentials = Buffer.from(credentials, 'utf-8').toString('base64')
  const tokenEndpoint = 'https://api.faceit.com/auth/v1/oauth/token'

  app.post('/register', async (request) => {
    const { code } = request.body
    const requestBody = qs.stringify({
      grant_type: 'authorization_code',
      code,
    })

    const headers = {
      Authorization: `Basic ${base64Credentials}`,
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }

    try {
      const tokenResponse = await axios.post(tokenEndpoint, requestBody, {
        headers,
      })
      return tokenResponse.data
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message)
      return {
        error,
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I am geting 401 BAD REQUEST error when testing

I tried everything, and I never cant get answer from this endpoint, but he is on the most recent doc that faceit posted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a URL-encoded base64 string from your credentials. This means that in the resulting base64 string you have to change these characters:

- remove any `=`
- change any `+` to `-`
- change any `/` to `_`

A code like this should do the trick:

```js
const urlEncodedString = base64String
    .replace(/=/g, '')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_')
```

Comment: It was a environment variable problem, that did not  updated on my application, so the client Id was mismatching, but thanks for the help.